# Display data LIke HTML Table In Android

Tags: android, tablelayout

```
..................................................
Name               Item                  Quantity
..................................................
a                    b                      20
b                    c                      80
d                    f                      90
f                    s                      80
.
.
.
```

In my project, I need to display data like this in a single text view.

This means that all data will be stored in a single string.

Because also need to print same view.

Can you please tell me how I can make this kind of string/output?

Comment: u can use table layout in android

Comment: need to show only in a single text view then how can use table layout and also this string sent for a print data

Comment: The string you're getting from print data consists of `html tags`?

Comment: no i want to make a view and put print button when user click on print button then print same view

Answer (score 0):

Use subString method to split the string using the spaces in between or any logic u preferred and the place the subString values in tableLayout and place images for lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is not efficient using single textview to display all your data.
You can split your data string and then you distribute them into table layout 
or you can just use a webview and write your data as HTML in a single string

if you use one of them, you can also keep your data string and you can print as you wish.

Comment: How can i get String from web View